# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid: Is there a way to get the corresponding column name, when clicking in a data cell in the Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a Dynamic Action which should get the data from the model, depending on the clicked column. Let 's say I have two columns in the interactive grid, column A and B. Depending on the column I clicked in, the DA should be executed and execute a query with the value from column A or B.

The DA is actived on doubleclick and I have the following source to get the value from the IG model.

```
var regionStaticId = $(this.triggeringElement).closest("div.js-apex-region").attr('id');
var grid   = apex.region( regionStaticId ).widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
var model  = grid.model;
var record = grid.getSelectedRecords()[0];
var value;

// Code to find the the clicked column comes here

if (record) {
  value = model.getValue(record, columnName);
}
```

Now, what I can do is add an extra css class to the particular cells, with the name of the source column. But that would be like hardcoding in my opinion. Like this.

```
if ($(this.triggeringElement).hasClass('columnA')) {
  columnName = 'COLUMN_A';
}
else if ($(this.triggeringElement).hasClass('columnB')) {
  columnName = 'COLUMN_B';
}
```

Is there a way to determine the clicked column, based on the triggering element?

Help is very much appreciated.